# Accessing database from rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console

When I open my rails console, running ./script/console (script folder contains a console file) , I input in the console Users.find(:all) and I get this message

```
'NameError: uninitialized constant User
    from (irb):1
'
```

I have similar message each time I run a commnad in the console (knowing I didn't connect by irb). I googled it and saw some similar issues that were asked on stack, and I didn't get any satisfactory answer. Someone has an idea ?

Eidt 1 : I don't konow if it is usefull, but here's as suggested to be posted the user model class

```
require "digest/sha1"
require_dependency "event"

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include UrlLinting
  include Gitorious::Authorization

  has_many :projects
  has_many :memberships, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :groups, :through => :memberships
  has_many :repositories, :as => :owner, :conditions => ["kind != ?", Repository::KIND_WIKI],
    :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :cloneable_repositories, :class_name => "Repository",
     :conditions => ["kind != ?", Repository::KIND_TRACKING_REPO]
  has_many :committerships, :as => :committer, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :commit_repositories, :through => :committerships, :source => :repository,
  :conditions => ["repositories.kind NOT IN (?)", Repository::KINDS_INTERNAL_REPO]
  has_many :ssh_keys, :order => "id desc", :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :comments
  has_many :email_aliases, :class_name => "Email", :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :events, :order => "events.created_at asc", :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :events_as_target, :class_name => "Event", :as => :target
  has_many :favorites, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :feed_items, :foreign_key => "watcher_id"
  has_many :content_memberships, :as => :member

  # Virtual attribute for the unencrypted password
  attr_accessor :password, :current_password

  attr_protected :login, :is_admin, :password, :current_password

  # For new users we are a little more strict than for existing ones.
  USERNAME_FORMAT = /[a-z0-9\-_\.]+/i.freeze
  USERNAME_FORMAT_ON_CREATE = /[a-z0-9\-]+/.freeze
  validates_presence_of     :login, :email,               :if => :password_required?
  validates_format_of       :login, :with => /^#{USERNAME_FORMAT_ON_CREATE}$/i, :on => :create
  validates_format_of       :login, :with => /^#{USERNAME_FORMAT}$/i, :on => :update
  validates_format_of       :email, :with => Email::FORMAT
  validates_presence_of     :password,                   :if => :password_required?
  validates_presence_of     :password_confirmation,      :if => :password_required?
  validates_length_of       :password, :within => 4..40, :if => :password_required?
  validates_confirmation_of :password,                   :if => :password_required?
  validates_length_of       :login,    :within => 3..40
  validates_length_of       :email,    :within => 3..100
  validates_uniqueness_of   :login, :email, :case_sensitive => false
  validates_acceptance_of :terms_of_use, :on => :create, :allow_nil => false
  validates_format_of     :avatar_file_name, :with => /\.(jpe?g|gif|png|bmp|svg|ico)$/i, :allow_blank => true

  before_save :encrypt_password
  before_create :make_activation_code
  before_validation :lint_identity_url, :downcase_login
  after_save :expire_avatar_email_caches_if_avatar_was_changed
  after_destroy :expire_avatar_email_caches

  state_machine :aasm_state, :initial => :pending do
    state :terms_accepted

    event :accept_terms do
      transition :pending => :terms_accepted
    end

  end
```

Edit 2 : when I run my console I have omitted some error messages (but the console loads)

```
 /var/www/gitorious/config/environment.rb:25:RuntimeError: Your config/gitorious.yml does not have an entry for your current Rails environment. Please consult config/gitorious.sample.yml for instructions.
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/rails/backtrace_cleaner.rb:2:NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::BacktraceCleaner
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/console_with_helpers.rb:5:NameError: uninitialized constant ApplicationController
```

Answer (score 3):

From the error, I can see that you called table from `irb`.
If you want to access to tables from the rails console, then in the command line instead of `irb` you should type:

```
rails console
```

Secondly, if you want to get all the records from users table, you should use:

```
User.all
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have `User` model defined like below:
`app/models/user.rb`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #Your things
end
```

Use model name (i.e) `User` not `Users`:

```
User.find(:all) or User.all  # This will display all user records
```

Comment: Sure I get the same message : NameError: uninitialized constant User
 from (irb):3

Comment: Then you don't have `User` model defined in `app/models`. Check your `app/models` n tell what u have..

Comment: Sure I do, I created user's accounts and I can log-in with them with no pb

Comment: could you post your user model and its file name??

Answer (score 1):

here's what did the trick : instead of running ./script/console, I ran

```
export RAILS_ENV=production && ./script/console
```